# Circle inside a circle character. What is it?

Tags: symbols, video-games

So I started playing Steins;Gate in Japanese the other day. And in one of the Tips about a character from the 雷ネット翔 , キラリちゃん is described as

> 頭が良くて、スポーツ万能。しかもカワイくて性格も〇

(But inside of 〇 is another circle...)

[image: Image of the circle in circle]

I don't know how to pronounce it and what it means...

Comment: I read that as 抜群、ばつぐん.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After doing some investigation, it seems that there are two Unicode characters which are made of a circle inside another circle:

- ◎ U+25CE BULLSEYE
- ⭗ U+2B57 HEAVY CIRCLE WITH CIRCLE INSIDE

In this Japanese context, only the first one ◎ appears to be appropriate ([Wiktionary](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E2%97%8E)), since it is known as 二重丸【にじゅうまる】 and is defined as 「とても良いことを示す記号。」, which suggests that it is indeed a stronger (double) variation of the more commonly used symbol ○ 丸【まる】「良いことを示す記号。」([Wiktionary](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E2%97%8B)).

So, 性格も◎ can probably be understood as something like "*very good* character too"...

Comment: How would I read that?

Comment: @SimonRichter にじゅうまる as above.

Comment: @broccolifacemask-cloth, even in a sentence like in the OP's picture?

Comment: @SimonRichter Yes, that's what I'm used to do.